# xPath or operator two compute more than two?

Tags: php, xpath

This is my xPath, however I see that the | operator computes only 2? How can I make it more than two? I posted my code below

```
function extractNodeValue($query, $xPath, $attribute = null) {
    $node = $xPath->query("//{$query}")->item(0);
    if (!$node) {
        return null;
    }
    return $attribute ? $node->getAttribute($attribute) : $node->nodeValue;
}


$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTMLfile(${'html'.$i});
$xPath = new DOMXpath($document);

    $tel = extractNodeValue('//*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div[3]/div[4] | //*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div[3]/div[3] | //*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div[3]/div[5]',$xPath);
```

Comment: If you're referring to the `extractNodeValue()` in your earlier answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17287590/how-to-change-the-variable-of-loadhtmlfile-with-a-loop), you should give a link to it.

Comment: `|` is a union operator (not "or"). It's a binary operator, i.e. it takes two arguments; but you can string them together, as you have, to perform a union of any number of args. The size of the resulting node-set is not limited. However, the `extractNodeValue()` you defined earlier only returns the value of the first node in the node-set.

Comment: Looks like the `extractNodeValue()` is now a total stupidity. And also the fourth if not even fifth question about it. You should start to think about how to come out of this madness with that function.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `2+2+2`, the `+` is a binary operator; your expression means `(2+2)+2`.

Similarly `|` in XPath is a binary operator, but because the result is of the same type as the operands, it composes with itself in the same way: `$x|$y|$z` means `($x|$y)|$z`.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath query you're passing on as to your `extractNodeValue` function will result in **//a | b | c**, which will only return `a` nodes, ignoring `b` and `c` nodes.

Probably you want to run **//a | //b | //c** to fetch the 1st occurrence of an `a`, `b` or `c` node, right?

If that's the case you have to change the way you're using the `$query` argument to something like this:

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
    <div>
        <a>Empire Burlesque</a>
        <b>Bob Dylan</b>
        <i>USA</i>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a>Hide your heart</a>
        <b>Bonnie Tyler</b>
        <i>UK</i>
    </div>
</html>
HTML;

function extractNodeValue($query, $xPath, $attribute = null) {
    $node = $xPath->query($query)->item(0);
    if (!$node) {
        return null;
    }

    return $attribute ? $node->getAttribute($attribute) : $node->nodeValue;
}

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);
$xPath = new DOMXpath($document);

$tel = extractNodeValue('//a | //b | //i', $xPath);
echo $tel;
```

#### Output:

```
Empire Burlesque
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I can't get it working, I get NULL when using it on the actual links and `var_dump`. This is an actual example: `$tel = extractNodeValue('//*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div[3]/div[4] | //*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div[3]/div[3]',$xPath);`

Comment: Can you paste an example of your HTML source? If you're getting NULL then probably your XPath expression is wrong.

Comment: And what is the particular info you're looking to retrieve from those pages?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your question leads somehow in the wrong direction.
There is nothing wrong with the xpaht. As already pointed out here the number of nodes which would be found by xpath query `|` is  not limited.

But you are using `->item(0);` in extractNodeValue()  which will only look at the first item.

If you like to output the "values" of all found nodes try something like this:

```
function extractNodeValue($node, $attribute = null) {

    if (!$node) {
        return null;
    }
    return $attribute ? $node->getAttribute($attribute) : $node->nodeValue;
}

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML(${'html'.$i});
$xPath = new DOMXpath($document);

$nodes = $xPath->query('//a | //b | //c');
foreach($nodes as $n) {
    $tel = extractNodeValue($n);
    echo $tel;
}
```

If this does not work, than most likely your html page does not match with your xapth expression.

**Update**
Looking to the html page in your comment:
To get the phone number try this:

```
$tel = extractNodeValue('//div[@id="eventDetailInfo"]//div[@class= "tel"]',$xPath);
```

Which returns:

```
string(15) "Phone: 22674608"
```

Comment: @Kaoukkos: To get the phone number try this: `$tel = extractNodeValue('//div[@id="eventDetailInfo"]//div[@class= "tel"]',$xPath);`. Which returns `string(15) "Phone: 22674608"`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already pointed out, your telephone query is going to produce multiple nodes, but your `extractNodeValue` function only returns one of them. My suggestion would be to rewrite it like this:

```
function extractNodeValue($query, $xPath, $attribute = null) {
  $values = array();
  foreach($xPath->query("//{$query}") as $node) {
    $values[] = $attribute ? $node->getAttribute($attribute) : $node->nodeValue;
  }
  return join($values, ", ");
}
```

This returns the multiple values in a single comma separated string, but it is easy enough to change the separator, or return the values as an array if that is more useful to you.

I would also suggest getting rid of the "//" that is added to the query here and include that in the calling code instead. Otherwise you end up with it being added twice in some cases. But that's not essential to fix at this point.

As for the telephone query itself, your query depends on the telephone div being in certain fixed positions, which isn't at all reliable (on some pages it matches the website and email address too).

It looks to me like there are two distinct cases you need to match: under the "Where" div (div 3 of the *eventDetailInfo* section), and under the "Contact" div (div 4).

Under the "Where" div, the telephone number can be in various positions, but they always have a class of "tel", so the safest query might be something like this:

```
//*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div[3]/*[@class="tel"]
```

Under the "Contact" div, the telephone number can also be in various positions, but there isn't any class on the telephone div that you can match on. However, the content in that div always starts with the string "Phone:", so one solution would be to use the XPath `starts-with` function.

```
//*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]/div[4]/div[starts-with(.,"Phone:")]
```

You could then combine those two queries with a union (`|`) operator to cover both cases. Alternatively (and I think this is a better solution), you could just use the second query for both cases by making it more generic, like this:

```
//*[@id="eventDetailInfo"]//div[starts-with(.,"Phone:")]
```

A possible downside is that this no longer limits the search to the "Where" and "Contact" divs, so if there are phone numbers in other parts of the *eventDetailInfo* section, it will match those too (although that may be a good thing).

Note that even without the union, this query still returns multiple nodes on some pages. So either way, it's vital that you use the updated `extractNodeValue` function if you want to get all of the values.